# Why do we need the equation of pair of straight lines?

Tags: coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

I was studying about the straight lines in coordinate geometry and came across this topic named 'pair of straight lines'. It started in my book directly with "If we multiply the equation of two lines the resulting algebraic equation must be satisfied by the points on both the lines." **I don't understand why we had to start this concept. What are the uses of this? And what does that two degree equation mean?**

If you don't remember this concept here's something to remind you.

If we have two lines $p_1x+q_1y+r_1=0$ and $p_2x+q_2y+r_2=0$ then equation of pair of lines is given by $$(p_1x+q_1y+r_1)(p_2x+q_2y+r_2)=0$$ If we solve this equation we get a two degree equation in the form of $$ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2fx+2gy+c=0$$ [Here](http://www.codecogs.com/library/maths/geometry/coordinate/pairs-of-straight-lines.php) is something to make you sure what I am talking about.

I assume this concept is equally applicable for conic sections. If I assume right then  I hope there won't be much to discuss for them about their uses after discussing them for straight lines.

Comment: I think it's just because it's a "degenerate" case of a conic section; depending on how the plane cuts the double cone, you get different kinds of curve: http://teachertech.rice.edu/Participants/dchipman/lessons/trajectories/conicsection.htm

Comment: @Aky If a plane cuts it...we get a single line...not two...

Comment: did you look at the image in the link in my first comment? It should clarify why it's a pair of lines.

Comment: @Aky U mean that diagram of intersecting lines?...it's something new i saw...so what does this two degree equation tells us about...? about the conic or the plane that is cutting the conic.?

Comment: Yes, that's the diagram I meant. Basically if you can factorize $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2fx+2gy+c=0$ into the form $(a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1)(a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2) = 0$ then you have a degenerate conic on your hands.

Comment: *I don't understand why we had to **start** this concept* - Probably for the same reason that Lent $($which will begin soon$)$ starts with the famous Parable of the Publican and the Pharisee, which teaches us how **NOT** to fast, so that we might know from the get go what to *avoid*. Likewise, the section on conics starts by first showing us which *binary quadratic polynomial equations* do **NOT** represent $($proper$)$ conics $($but rather degenerate ones$),$ so that we might not be fooled by mere appearances. :-$)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general equation represents a pair of line if $abc+2fgh=af^2+bg^2+ch^2$ thus its a part of conics and with a homogeneous second degree equation you can find point of intersection of conic with a line using partial differentiation which is very short and nice method.